# How to get image from android asset

Tags: android

EDIT

Hi I just newbie on Java and Android development, and I need help to get image from asset folder, I already try many ways to get work but not luck yet.

Here is my folder detail structure

[image]

I used Baker Android framework to create my application. 
Now, what I want is I want call image 1.jpg from image-bali folder and convet it to bitmap, I used this code to decode the file

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(assetManager + "/books/Individual Villas/images-bali/1.jpg", bitmapOptions);
```

Here my full code I used for

```
  AssetManager assetManager = getResources().getAssets();
  String path = "assetManager + "/books/Individual Villas/images-bali/1.jpg";


  BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
  bitmapOptions.inDither = true;// optional
  bitmapOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;// optional
  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path , bitmapOptions);

  Log.d("Test","Bitmap data " + bitmap);
```

When I'm load the code, it always crash my app.  Can anyone please guide me how to do this?

I would appreciate if I can have a detailed procedure, thanks.

**Log-Cat :**

```
07-31 16:17:15.694  12542-12542/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.baker.abaker.settings.Configuration.getFilesDirectory(Configuration.java:113)
            at com.baker.abaker.settings.Configuration.getMagazinesDirectory(Configuration.java:130)
            at com.baker.abaker.MagazineActivity$8.onClick(MagazineActivity.java:351)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4421)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18190)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-31 16:17:15.702      491-496/? E/SurfaceFlinger﹕ #### captureScreenImplLocked
07-31 16:17:16.046      519-571/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ !@Dumpstate > dumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
07-31 16:17:24.991      519-749/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 14914
07-31 16:17:46.343      519-571/? E/ViewRootImpl﹕ sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
07-31 16:17:46.515  12877-12877/? E/com.baker.abaker.GindActivity﹕ Could not load libraries: Couldn't load JavaScriptCore from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar:/data/app/com.baker.abaker.test-1.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/com.baker.abaker.test-1]: findLibrary returned null
07-31 16:17:46.694  12877-12877/? E/class com.baker.abaker.GindActivity﹕ USER ACCOUNT COULD NOT BE RETRIEVED, WILL USE ANDROID_ID.
07-31 16:17:46.710  12877-12877/? E/class com.baker.abaker.GindActivity﹕ No valid Google Play Services APK found.
07-31 16:17:47.991      491-496/? E/SurfaceFlinger﹕ #### captureScreenImplLocked
07-31 16:17:48.030     519-1773/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager﹕ ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
07-31 16:17:48.163  12877-12877/? E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /file:/android_asset/books/Individual Villas/images-bali/1.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
07-31 16:17:48.265  12877-12898/? E/dalvikvm﹕ adjustAdaptiveCoef max=4194304, min=1048576, ut=568
07-31 16:17:48.390  12877-12880/? E/dalvikvm﹕ adjustAdaptiveCoef max=6291456, min=1572864, ut=368
07-31 16:17:48.530      519-882/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager﹕ ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
07-31 16:17:50.421  12877-12877/? E/Web Console﹕ Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of null:1073
07-31 16:17:50.718  12877-12877/? E/Web Console﹕ Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of null:1073
07-31 16:17:54.991      519-749/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 14915
```

Comment: keep in drawable folder and access it

Comment: @Androidiseverythingforme, hmmm can not access the folder asset??? thanks for quick comment :)

Comment: You missing the gallary folder in your path : `String path = "assetManager + "/books/Individual Villas/images-bali/gallery/1.jpg";`

Comment: Hi @ved, thanks for the comment, image 1.jpg is outside of gallery folder :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Thing  you should do is that change name of the folders...
use _ (underscore) instead of white-space or - (dash).....

then....
Try This Code to get File...

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream istr = null;
    try {
        istr = assetManager.open("books/IndividualVillas/images_bali/1.jpg");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
    return bitmap;
```

Comment: I replace the code with your but still not working, I got null output AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
                InputStream istr = null;
                try {
                    istr = assetManager.open("/books/IndividualVillas/images-bali/1.jpg");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr); Is I do wrong writen the code??? thanks :)

Comment: remove `-` from folder name.

Comment: Sorry I dint see that " remove - from folder name " , I will try now, but no error with your code, only give NULL output. thanks

Comment: Ohkk.. there may be null variable you are using...that's why it gives you null pointer Exception.. try to find it and solve it

Comment: Thanks, still get NULL now even I used underscore instead of dash, but that make me learn something, thanks for you help :)

Comment: I was do mistake I forgot to remove "/" in front of books, your code is working awesome, thanks mate :)

Answer (score 1):

remove  getResources().

```
    AssetManager assetManager =getAssets();

 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(assetManager+"/books/IndividualVillas/images-bali/1.jpg");
 Bitmap dest = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

also remove the space on folder name

Comment: I try remove getResources() not working also but my app not crashing anymore, but Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path , bitmapOptions); give null output, thanks a lot

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code, but is not working :(, give a crash for the app again now. I tried access the code within click button, is that make any problem??

Answer (score 0):

You can't use white spaces in the path of the assets folder.
 Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /file:/android_asset/books/Individual Villas/images-bali/1.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, I removed the white space for the folder name, it also not help, what I got now is NULL output for Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path , bitmapOptions);

Comment: Here the log I got now 07-31 16:32:38.147  15339-15339/? D/Test﹕ Bitmap Data :null and I log also the path file I got 07-31 16:32:38.147  15339-15339/? D/Test﹕ File path is android.content.res.AssetManager@41c84ff8/books/IndividualVillas/images-bali/1.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You should save it as a drawable because you can get a drawable object from an inputstream. use the inputstream to get your asses. Something like this:

```
try {
        InputStream stream = context.getAssets().open("path/image.jpg");
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(stream, null);
        yourImageview.setImageDrawable(d);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Source: https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/10/02/store-and-use-files-in-assets/

Answer (score 0):

Keep your Asset folder reference to Root directory currently it is **rooted to your "src/main",** for do this **copy your "asset folder"** and right click on root directory means "ABaker" and paste it. after that **delete the asset folder from "src/main"** 
and apply this code.

```
try {
        // get input stream
        InputStream is = getAssets().open(
                "/books/Individual Villas/images-bali/1.jpg");
        // load image as Drawable
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, null);
        // set image to ImageView
        img_view.setImageDrawable(d);
    } catch (IOException ex) {

    }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment, the problem is solved by @Prag's, your code also good just remove the "/" in front of books folder name, "/" will give you NULL output :), thanks